# Use python to resample a raster 12 times in increments of 10

Tags: arcpy, resolution, resampling

Objective: I want to take a sample landscape (with a resolution of 10,10) and resample it systematically in increments of 10 until a max of 130,130 (and eventually write each new rasters file path to a .csv so I can batch import them into FRAGSATS) -- but first things first :P

I originally did the resample in ArcGIS modelbuilder and then exported it to python, but that didn't help much because iterate etc is a modelbuilder specific.
I am having trouble organizing the for loop. Thinking maybe a function would be better?

```
#import mods
import arcpy, os, sys

#ask students for the for the sample landscape
raster = "\\" + raw_input("Raster name and ext?:  " )
print raster

#makes an output folder 
out_filepath = root + "\\resampled"
print out_filepath 

try:
    os.makedirs(out_filepath)
    except OSError:
             pass

#set the workspace an check to see the file is there
arcpy.env.workspace = root 
print os.path.exists(root + raster)

#resample
for num in range(11):  
       x = range(10,130,10)
       out_filepath = root + "\\resampled"
       arcpy.Resample_management(raster_tif, resample_tif, x , "MAJORITY")
print "Resampling complete and results transfered to folder"
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__   File "C:\Users\jdrid\Desktop\604_Tutorial\python\resample.py", line 34, in <module>
    arcpy.Resample_management(raster_tif, resample_tif, x , "MAJORITY")   
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 14044, in Resample
    raise e RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Comment: As you will see in the [advice on writing code snippets](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers), I think it is best to remove `try`/`except` statements while testing, and from any code presented here.

Comment: x = range(10,130,10) should be x = range(10,140,10) as the last value is not in the list (or you can append it after creating the range) and then actually *use* the range. You need to increment the resample_tif or you will be overwriting the same file every time.. out_filepath is not used.

Comment: Yes that's correct, thanks. I am using 10.3.1 and I want to create 11 additional rasters from the sample landscape with increasing resolution in increments of 10. I don't want to overwrite the resampled tiffs. I need 12 rasters in total. @MichaelMiles-Stimson

The sample has 10m resolution

Answer (score 2):

I can see you're starting out, here's a few tips:

```
raster = raw_input("Raster name and ext?:  " )
rName,rExt = os.path.splitext(raster) # separate name and extension
if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(root,raster)):
    x = range(10,140,10)
    for i in x:
        resample_tif = '{}\\resampled\\{}_{}m{}'.format(root,rName,i,rExt)
        print "Output is " + resample_tif
        arcpy.Resample_management(os.path.join(root,raster), resample_tif, i , "MAJORITY")
```

You've got [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) which is a good thing but in this case [arcpy.Exists](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000069000000) is better: the file exists *and it's a GIS type*, then you need to use the output of Exists to branch - no point continuing if the file doesn't exist. Note that os.path.exists will return True if the input is a folder as well.

It's not good to include the `'\\'` with the file name, it would just cause problems later.. use os.path.join to join the folder and file name - this adds the operating system sep char for breaking paths and should work on Windows, Linux and Mac correctly.

[Range](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/python-range-function) does not include the end, so go one increment more or create the `range = (start, end, step)` then `range.append(end)` to ensure the last value is included.

Alter your output file name or you're overwriting on each iteration and will only have the last file name. I have used the format like if your image is `c:\temp\raster.tif` your output will be `c:\temp\resampled\raster_XXm.tif` using the [string format operation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: OK wow. Thanks for the great -- and timely feedback. I'll play around with it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

[Python rang](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/) does not include the end number, because start index always starts with zero and last = last-1 so go one increment by1 to ensure the last value is included.